# How Do I Find & Fix A Error In Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

So I get the error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0).

**I found out the error is in the method `viewDidLoad()` on `super.viewDidLoad()`**

```
import UIKit

class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var timelineData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

@IBAction func loadData(){
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimeLineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Jabbs")

    findTimeLineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

        if !(error != nil){
            for object:PFObject! in objects as [PFObject]{
                self.timelineData.addObject(object)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.loadData()

    var footerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView

    var logoutButton:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 50, 20)
    logoutButton.setTitle("Logout", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    logoutButton.addTarget(self, action: "logout", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    footerView.addSubview(logoutButton)


    if ((PFUser.currentUser()) == nil){
        self.showLoginSignUp()
    }


}


func showLoginSignUp(){
    var loginAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up / Login", message: "Please sign up or login",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
        textfield in
        textfield.placeholder = "Your Username"
    })

    loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
        textfield in
        textfield.placeholder = "Your Password"
        textfield.secureTextEntry = true
    })

    loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        alertAction in
        let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
        let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
        let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextfield.text, password: passwordTextfield.text){
            (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if ((user) != nil){
                println("Login Successful")
            }else{
                println("Login Failed, Username/Password are Incorrect")
            }

        }



    }))


    loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        alertAction in
        let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
        let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
        let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

        var jabber:PFUser = PFUser()
        jabber.username = usernameTextfield.text
        jabber.password = passwordTextfield.text

        jabber.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (success:Bool!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if !(error != nil){
                println("Sign Up Successfull")
                var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
                imagePicker.delegate = self

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
                let errorString = error.userInfo!["error"] as NSString
                println(errorString)
            }

        }




    }))

    self.presentViewController(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!) {
    let pickedImage:UIImage = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as UIImage

    // Scale down image
    let scaledImage = self.scaleImageWith(pickedImage, and: CGSizeMake(95, 95))

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage)

    let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)

    PFUser.currentUser().setObject(imageFile, forKey: "profileImage")
    PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

}

func scaleImageWith(image:UIImage, and newSize:CGSize)->UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

func logout(sender:UIButton){
    PFUser.logOut()
    self.showLoginSignUp()
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return timelineData.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:JabbTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as JabbTableViewCell

    let jabb:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject

    cell.jabbTextView.alpha = 0
    cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0

    cell.jabbTextView.text = jabb.objectForKey("content") as String


    var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(jabb.createdAt)

    var findJabber:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    findJabber.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: jabb.objectForKey("jabber").objectId)

    findJabber.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
        if !(error != nil){
            let user:PFUser! = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

            // Profile Image
            cell.profileImageView.alpha = 0

            let profileImage:PFFile = user["profileImage"] as PFFile

            profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!)->Void in

                if !(error != nil){
                    let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    cell.profileImageView.image = image
                }
            }

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                cell.jabbTextView.alpha = 1
                cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.profileImageView.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What happens if in `loadData()` you remove the implicitly unwrapped: `for object:PFObject! in objects as [PFObject] {` becomes `for object:PFObject in objects as [PFObject] {`

Comment: @Antonio I get the same error

Comment: I suggest you to put some breakpoints at beginning of each method, so to narrow down options and have at least one method to look into - then try to step line by line until you reach the line where the exception is generated

Comment: @Antonio I did what you said and it is the `super.viewDidLoad()` line under the method `viewDidLoad()` how do I fix it. P.S. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In that case it's not your code crashing... that makes tracking the down problem almost impossible. Only thing I can think of is checking if there's any dead outlet connection in IB

Comment: @VBtutorials are you willing/able to post to github?  Then some of us can help debug with you.

Comment: @SteveRosenberg Yes, but how do I do that

Comment: https://github.com  You'll have to create an account.  You can download and install the client for Mac also.  There is some effort here getting started but a very very valuable resources to use.

Comment: @SteveRosenberg https://github.com/aliengooey/Jabber

Comment: Complex.  Not obvious on first 5 minutes.  I have to head out, but will spend more time later if you haven't solved it by then.

Comment: @SteveRosenberg Could you possibly work on it for me this weekend. I might do a test release for certain people soon and this error is holding the release date for that back. When the app is finished I WILL be sure to put your name in the contributors section. Many thanks ahead of time - VB

Comment: Sure thing!  Hope I find it.  Do you have earlier versions without the bug?

Comment: @SteveRosenberg Sorry, I don't, but I traced it to the method `viewDidLoad()` and `super.viewDidLoad`(in the method). Which is in the TimelineTableViewController.swift file

Comment: Noted.  I will heck it out.

Comment: ok - I tried my best.  There are multiple errors,.  I don't think I can trace/fix all of them without a complete logic review of the entire app.  Which for an outsider might be easier to write from scratch.  Several of your array calls are giving errors.   My recommendation is to go t earlier working versions and and build up again.  Or separate the login from the tableview.  Get them each working separately.  Sorry.